# Probability of failing an exam set based on individual exam failure probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

So the question is as follows:

X need to pass four out of five separate tests for certification. Assume that the tests are equally difficult, and that the performance on separate tests are independent.

If the probability of failing each separate test is p = 0.15, then what is the probability of failing certification?

So I tried the binomial distribution, effectively seeing what are the chances of passing at least 4 exams (and failing one) and then adding the probability of passing all 5 exams. 
This yields an overall failure probability of just over 0.16. Is this a correct approach?

Thank you!

Comment: @angryavian What answer do you get?  I'm seeing $0.16479$

Comment: Basically for the failure probability I did: 1- (5 4)p^4(1-p) + p^5 where (5 4) is the number of combinations with one failure

Comment: They might be getting $.47799$ if they're not multiplying the number of ways of passing with $4$ good exams by $5$.

Comment: @Andy   Well, you're missing some brackets (or you need to change the sign on $p^5$), but I essentially agree.

Comment: @lulu Oops, yeah that should have been in the bracket

Comment: Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah , your approach is correct.
Look, Probability of passing certification = (0.85)^5 + 5*C1*(0.15)*(0.85)^4
(As in this case he will clear all subjects or will be failed only in a single subject)

So Probability of passing certification = 0.4437+ 0.3915 = 0.83521
Thus required probability of failing certification = 1 - 0.83521 = 0.16479